# Combine one image + one audio (53 hours) file to make one video using FFmpeg without taking long time

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to make a video from an image and an audio which is 53 hours long.
is there any ffmpeg command can do it without taking forever

Comment: The rendering time depends on the codec and length of the files used.

Comment: What is the use case? Why do you need to make a video from an image?

Comment: to use it as a YouTube  video